# Cut string on every nth line of a very large document

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx, string, large-files

I have document A here:

```
@rand1
ABCDEFBHIJKLM
+
<</////
@rand2
NOPQRSTUVW
+
<<//<<<
@anotherrand
XYZABCDE
+
<<//<<<
```

I would like to have an output that contains all the lines of document A but where the lines 2,6,10... (pattern is 2+n*4)have been trimmed to only have the first 3 characters for example. This output would look like this:

```
@rand1
ABC
+
<</////
@rand2
NOP
+
<<//<<<
@anotherrand
XYZ
+
<<//<<<
```

I am doing this on a very big file (>10 million lines) and can't seem to find a way to make this go very quickly. the below code accomplishes what I want, but takes way too long:

```
r=0 #line number of documentA being read
l=2 #line that needs to be trimmed

while read line; do
  r=$(echo $r +1 | bc)
  echo $r
  if [ $r == $l ]
  then
    echo $line | cut -c -3 >> outputfile
    l=$(echo $l + 4 | bc)
  else
    echo $line >> outputfile
  fi
done < document A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed (available as `gsed` on OSX) using the "n skip m" address operator:

```
sed -E '2~4s/(.{3}).*/\1/' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: this seems to work if I use gsed but not sed on my Mac. Also I would ideally have the 3 be a bash variable here which would usually be accomplished by simply putting the command in double quotations, but doing so results in this error: gsed: -e expression #1, char 16: Invalid content of \{\}. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: @DNA_bash are you sure that your variable is wholly numeric (no leading/trailing whitespace for example)? which shell are you using?

Comment: ah stupid mistake from me, you are correct there was as space at the end I didn't see! Thank you!

Comment: @DNA_bash you're welcome - I hope it is significantly faster than your original method?

Comment: Yes! Takes less than a minute and my way I estimated would take more than 24h!